# Sending voice over the net and get it with HTML5 and mobile apps

Tags: audio, stream, broadcast

I'm trying to put in place a basic streaming system from the browser.
The idea is to let the user stream audio live from his mic through the browser and then allow others to listen to this stream with their browser (desktop, mobile, etc ...) and iOS/Android apps.

I started doing some tests with the `Red5 Server` (which is a great free alternative to the Flash Media Server). 
With this technologie, I can publish a stream with the `RTMP` (ex: `rtmp://myserver/myApp`).
But the problem is that I can't find a way to read the published stream on other plateforms (using the video tag with HTML5, in iOS, etc ...).

As i failed to that, my question is:

How can I let a user to stream his voice over the net (using flash or not) and then allow the others to listen to that stream by using lightweight technologies (HTML5) and mobile apps?

Thanks,

Regards

Comment: There is no standard html5 tags that will allow for sending audio, only receiving. That being said you need to use a 3rd party framework to so the sending, flash or other browser plugin. Most mobile devices (all iOS for example) wont do plugins, so you could go mobile app (non browser) for sending, but at that point you might as well use the app to receive as well. ...Skype... but yeah, the browser only (no plugins) is not going to happen for sending.

Comment: @Justin808: Thanks for your comment but I don't think you did understand the post: I can accept sending from a browser using flash. But using which tool? Is there a tool that can take the sent stream and turns it into a standard format? (I want to install that tool by myself to see how it works). I tried with red5 but in the doc there is no mention on how to convert a RTMP stream into H.264 for example.

Comment: Thierry, I know that flash can access video and the mic. If you want to go that route you would have to write a flash application to send the stream to a server and from the server to other clients. As for conversion, you would have to write the tool yourself, unless you can find one. I'm sure there are ones for sale, but they probably aren't cheep.

Comment: @Justin808: Thanks again for the answer. I still believe there is a method/tool that can take that sent stream and convert it into a standard one. As a student, the only think I can give is the 200 bounty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like RED5 should be able to do what you want...

0.9.0 RC2 has the ability to:

- Streaming Audio (MP3, F4A, M4A)
- Recording Client Streams (FLV only)

some links that may help:

- http://osflash.org/pipermail/red5_osflash.org/2007-April/010400.html
- http://www.red5chat.com/

Answer (score 0):

Though not exactly what you're after, you could take a look at [BigBlueButton](http://www.bigbluebutton.org) which is a web conferencing suite based on open source components ([RED5](http://red5.org) is one of them). It's has a rather complex architecture but they do have a flash based client you can take a loot at.